# Get URL for featured image for posts?

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails

I'm using [Essential Grid](https://www.themepunch.com/essgrid-doc/essential-grid-documentation/) plugin to create a custom meta field for posts. I've created a simple image field. The plan is to add the URL of the featured image. Problem is I'm not sure how to get the physical URL.

For instance, I'm trying to get `/mysite.com/wp-contents/uploads/my-image.jpg`.

What's the best and fastest way to get the URL?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using the featured image functionality already built into WP?

Comment: The plugin I'm using needs something like %custom_image% to display the image. Just using the featured image doesn't create it.

Comment: Ah, so you're not recreating it at all, you're trying to put the URL into your meta field via placeholders/substitution?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Just looking for a faster method to get the URL.

Comment: How are your fields being output on the frontend? Which plugin do you use?

Comment: The plugin is called Essential Grid plugin. I updated my question with plugin name as well.

Answer (score 1):

The function to use would be:

```
$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
```

However, that's not the most helpful for you right now, so we have a meta field with placeholders that you need to swap out for URLs before outputting.

breaking that down we get these smaller steps:

```
// grab the field
// grab the URL
// swap the placeholder out for the URL
// output the field
```

So lets do each individual bit:

```
// grab the field
$meta = get_post_meta( ....

// grab the URL
$thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

// swap the thumbnail placeholder out for the URL
$meta = str_replace( '%thumbnail%', $thumb_url, $meta );

// output the meta field
echo wp_kses_post( $meta );
```

Notice the `wp_kses_post` which strips out dangerous HTML while letting you keep `img` tags etc

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not the best at this, but would this code go into my `functions.php` file and then I can use `%thumbnail%`?

Comment: No, this isn't an action or filter, it goes in the place you use the meta fields on the frontend. However, I don't know where you use it, and you never say, nor do you indicate which plugin you're using. It may be that your mystery plugin does all the frontend stuff already, in which case nobody on this site can help you can your question is offtopic, only the community for that unnamed plugin can.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my initial question with the plugin in question. The plugin I'm using is the Essential Grid plugin. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Oooh, nope you're not going to be able to do this with this answer, you're going to need to dig into the dev docs for the essential grid plugin or contact their dev support

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the post's featured image URI, you can use the [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/):

```
$uri = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, $size );
```

Comment: I'm creating the custom meta field inside of my WP admin. I'm not sure how I would use the above-mentioned code.

Comment: Without seeing any code and what you have tried, it's hard to tell how.

Comment: Right. I'm not even sure if there is any code to show. I'm just looking for the URL of the featured image to copy and paste.

Comment: In that case, you can click the featured image, and then copy the `URL` from the right side of opened modal.